# Event target only targeting first item in loop from localstorage

Tags: javascript

Working on a Spotify app for a practice where I'm storing searched artist object values into `localstorage` then I want to get the artist name with e.target but it's only logging the first result from `localstorage`. Why isn't it targeting every element created this way?

for instance, if I've searched and stored 4 artists, it only logs the name of the first object stored.

```js
object.keys(localStorage).forEach((key) => {
  artistObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  artistList = document.getElementById("displayResults");
  artistName = document.createElement("a");
  artistResult = document.createElement("li");
  artistName.innerHTML = artistObj[0].items[0].name;
  artistResult.appendChild(artistName);
  artistList.appendChild(artistResult);
});
artistName.addEventListener("click", getRelatedArtists);

function getRelatedArtists(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to add the event-listener inside the loop to add it for each element

```
object.keys(localStorage).forEach((key) => {
  let artistObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  let artistList = document.getElementById("displayResults");
  let artistName = document.createElement("a");
  let artistResult = document.createElement("li");
  
  artistName.innerHTML = artistObj[0].items[0].name;
  artistResult.appendChild(artistName);
  artistList.appendChild(artistResult);
  artistName.addEventListener("click", getRelatedArtists);
});


function getRelatedArtists(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
}
```

Comment: yes that too, thanks for mention i will edit it now

Comment: My first api project. Quite difficult honestly